# Kernel is not starting . Showing Invalid data or Dead kernel

Tags: python, python-3.x, kernel, jupyter

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ising\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1703, in _execute
result = await result

File "C:\Users\ising\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore

File "C:\Users\ising\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 69, in post
model = yield maybe_future(

File "C:\Users\ising\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
value = future.result()

File "C:\Users\ising\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore

File "C:\Users\ising\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)

File "C:\Users\ising\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
value = future.result()

File "C:\Users\ising\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore

File "C:\Users\ising\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 100, in start_kernel_for_session
kernel_id = yield maybe_future(

File "C:\Users\ising\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
value = future.result()

File "C:\Users\ising\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
yielded = next(result)

File "C:\Users\ising\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\ising\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 186, in start_kernel
km.start_kernel(**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\ising\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 304, in start_kernel
kernel_cmd, kw = self.pre_start_kernel(**kw)

File "C:\Users\ising\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 251, in pre_start_kernel
self.write_connection_file()

File "C:\Users\ising\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 468, in write_connection_file
self.connection_file, cfg = write_connection_file(self.connection_file,

File "C:\Users\ising\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 138, in write_connection_file
with secure_write(fname) as f:

File "C:\Users\ising\anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in **enter**
return next(self.gen)

File "C:\Users\ising\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 435, in secure_write
win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)

File "C:\Users\ising\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 361, in win32_restrict_file_to_user

```
import win32api
```

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried uninstalling and installing these things

**ipython**

**jupyter_client**

**jupyter_core**

and after that if it's not work then try using this command
**pip install -- pywin32==227** and use this command in **anaconda powershell prompt** only.